# HTTP client : Get request from webservice throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, web-services, exception, httpclient, application-server

I have following code that works fine when executing directly from Eclipse but when i am calling it from standard (Eclipse generated) client on Server (IBM WAS) then its giving exception.

```
  public Dispatcher() { //constructor
            try {           
                ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dispatchersettings", Locale.ENGLISH);
                server = "http://" + rb.getString("UserID") +":" + rb.getString("UserPassword")
                            + "@"+ rb.getString("ServerAppURL") + ":" + rb.getString("ServerAppPort")
                            + rb.getString("ServerAppContextPath"); 
            }
            catch (Exception configException) {
                configException.printStackTrace();
            }
}

public boolean sendTransactionUpdate(String name, String msgTitle, String msgContents, String transORalert) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); // auto-reads the response stream
        String responseBody = "";
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(  new URIBuilder( server + 
                    "/invoke?adapter=rcAdapter&procedure=sendTransactionUpdate")
                    .addParameter("parameters", "[\"" +name +"\",\"" + msgTitle+ "\",\"" + msgContents +"\",\"" + transORalert + "\"]").build() );
            try {
                System.out.println("Inside Webservice :Executing URL -->"  +httpget.toString() );
                responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                System.out.println( responseBody );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                httpget.releaseConnection();
            }
            if( responseBody.indexOf("\"isSuccessful\":true") > -1 )
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

It only reaches to the line 
**System.out.println("Inside Webservice :Executing URL -->"  +httpget.toString() );**

before 
**responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);**

I think above line should be causing this exception.

Its very weird that Its even **not going** in the catch block and showing exception. the below immediate block is not getting executed at all.

```
catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception LeveL 1:" + e.getMessage() );
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post full stack trace? Or show where the exception occurs.

Comment: Kindly, see the updated note above. BTW, it only shows exception on the client JSP page. no more Logs on server file. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. The Exception occurs on your application server?

Comment: Indeed, this the only exception on the client jsp, but nothing at backend logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue now. There were JAR files colliding with other jars on IBM WAS server. I was using Apache HTTP client (Base64) that probably was colliding with another jar on WAS (i don't know which jar on WAS).

So what i did, i used jarjar utility to rename Apache jar files.

After it, i just replaced old Apache HTTP jars in my project, and then compiled and deployed on WAS; and it worked fine.

hope this may help someone in future.

thanks